# Как получить json с сайта в android приложении?

Tags: java, android, json

[Есть сайт](https://steampay.com/games). Мне нужно оттуда вытащить `json` файл всех товаров (а на сайте ведь они выводятся по 20 штук автоподгрузкой). Я только начинаю и никак не могу понять, везде есть инфа как именно распарсить `json` файлы.

А как их с сайта **забрать**?

Comment: На этом сайте каталог товаров получается не с той ссылки, а при помощи ajax запроса, который выполняет загруженный код.

Comment: Боже, ещё и ajax теперь изучать, а его - то как выполнить?

Comment: Вы можете не учить Ajax, а выполнить запрос любым удобным для вас способом, например при помощи Fetch

Comment: Вы также можете подробно изучить отправляемые сайтом запросы используя вкладку Network в инструментах разработчика в браузере

Comment: спасибо большое! может подскажете, как действовать и с этими сайтами: https://zaka-zaka.com/ https://steambuy.com/ https://www.gameray.ru/?

Comment: Каждый сайт так или иначе формируют и отправляют запрос на сервер. Вы можете, скажем так, симулировать и выполнить запрос сколько вам угодно раз. Главное знать какие данные и на какой сервер отправляются для получения ответа. Но не забывайте про CORS, который не даст вам осуществлять кросс-доменные запросы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле вопрос задал криво и непонятно, поэтому и не получил конкретного ответа. Поскольку нужно было всё это для андроида, то использовал, разумеется, retrofit + gson.